# How do you specify a database column that contains a space in a linq statement

Tags: vb.net, linq, whitespace

I thought this would have been quite common but can't find anything on this.  I'm trying to query columns that have spaces immbedded within them.  For the life of me I don't see a way of selecting them when I'm trying to assign them to an alias when creating an anonymous type result.  Here's the code, but not sure how to go from here:

```
Dim joinedRows = (From r1 In ds.Tables(ETGAtSfdcTableName.Snapshot1) Group Join r2In ds.Tables   
                 (ETGAtSfdcTableName.Snapshot2) On r1.Field(Of String)("idAT") Equals 
                 r2.Field(Of String)("idAT") Into j() _
                        From c In j.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                                        Select New With _
                                        { _
                                             r1.idAT, _
                                             .status = r1.status, _
                                             ......                                                 
                                             .Change = r2.amtProdUSD - r1.amtProdUSD, _
                                             .ChangeABS = Abs(r2.amtProdUSD - r1.amtProdUSD), _
                                             r1.id, _
                                             amStatus = r1."Opportunity Status",
                                             ......
```

As you can see the column  "opportunity status" doesn't lend itself to be referenced this way.  is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What does Intellisense say? My guess would be r1.OpportunityStatus

Comment: Which LINQ? LINQ to XML? LINQ to Objects?

Comment: Well being that this is coming from a generic dataset, there's no intellisense available.

Comment: LINQ to DataSets and LINQ to Objects

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ to SQL will convert the space in the column name to an underscore: `Opportunity_Status`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
amStatus = r1.Field<string>("Opportunity Status")
```